# Is Google+ API going to shut down?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

According to this article
https://www.engadget.com/2018/10/08/google-shutting-down-google-plus/
Google is planning to  shut down its social network Google+ for consumers.  I was wondering if the Google+'s api is also going to be removed? In my case I am using this endpoint to retrieve user's public profile.
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Google+ APIs are shutting down.

> Google+ APIs will be shut down on **March 7, 2019**. This includes Google+ Sign-in. Learn more.
>
> Google+ integrations for web and mobile apps will also cease to function March 7, 2019. Learn more.
>
> This will be a progressive shutdown, with intermittent failures
>   starting as early as **January 28, 2019**.

From official site: https://developers.google.com/+/