# Google+ API not firing onSignIn call

Tags: angular, google-plus

I have an Angular project and I'm trying to create a button that allows a user to login to their Google+ account in order get information such as username, email and profile picture.
I have followed this tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in):

I added the following in my index.html page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

Then I added the following in my app.component.html

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

And then I finally added this callback function in my app.component.ts:

```
  onSignIn(googleUser)  {
    let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
  }
```

My issue is that the onSignIn callback function never gets called for some reason. Any ideas on why this is? I'm very responsive if you have questions.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google Plus has announced that they are shutting down in a few months anyway.

Comment: I think you are missing the `()` after `onSignIn` in your template. You can try to write `data-onsuccess="onSignIn($event)"` instead

Comment: @IngoBürk what are they going to replace it with?

Comment: Nothing, as far as I know. Though I'm not sure how this will affect the social logins... That's actually a good question.

Comment: @AugustinR unfortunately, that did not work

Comment: @sbattoh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487759/is-google-api-going-to-shut-down

Comment: @IngoBürk so many websites use google+ api for login that doesn't make any sense

Comment: I'm not Google, don't blame me… :-) This is all the information I found about it.

Comment: @IngoBürk I appreciate your help brother!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ API is shutting down in March 7th, 2019 so I have decided not to integrate this API. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487759/is-google-api-going-to-shut-down?noredirect=1&lq=1)